# Is J2EE 1.3 in End of Life stage?

Tags: jsp, servlets, jakarta-ee, ejb, jax-rpc

Would you please advise whether the following J2EE 1.3 specifications are in End-of-Life stage and there is no support from Oracle and IBM for these specifications?

```
JAXP 1.1,
JAX-RPC 1.1,
EJB 2.0,
JCA 1.0,
JSP 1.2 and
Servlet 2.3
```

Answer (score 4):

The specifications are simply documents. They don't require maintenance or support, and therefore don't have an end-of-life.

On the other hand, implementations of the respective specifications *could* be subject to end-of-life considerations.  But that would depend on the respective vendors ... and the degree to which active maintenance and support are required or provided.

So, your question should really be about EOL for specific products that implement J2EE specifications.

---

The other thing to note is that the EE specifications are upwards compatible.  So, a web application that (for example) required a Servlet 2.3 implementation should work on a 2.4 or 3.0 implementation ... modulo that there aren't compatibility issues in platform-specific extensions, etc.

(But the same is true for versions of Java.)